# How to Open new browser Window without closing previous window using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I'm using below code to open new browser window but it is opening link in the same tab :-( . I want to open new browser window with clearing all cookies without closing first one window.

```
    `      Actions act = new Actions(driver);
    act.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys("N").build().perform();
    driver.get("https://www.facebook.com");`
```

I tried this code too but it did't help me out :
            `Robot robot = new Robot();
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_N);
            driver.get("https://www.facebook.com");`

Any help would be appericated !!

Answer (score 1):

First thing is your key combination to open a new window is incorrent. Correct key combination would be **Control + N**

And when you open the new window, you need to **focus** to that new window

You can use the below code snippet to open a new browser window and navigate to an url. This is using `Robot` class in `java.awt.Robot` package.

```
public void openNewWindow(String url) throws AWTException {

    // Initialize the robot class object
    Robot robot = new Robot();

    // Press and hold Control and N keys
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_N);

    // Release Control and N keys
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_N);

    // Set focus to the newly opened browser window
    ArrayList <String> tabs = new ArrayList<String> (driver.getWindowHandles());
    driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(tabs.size()-1));
    for (String windowHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
        driver.switchTo().window(windowHandle);
    }

    // Continue your actions in the new browser window
    driver.get(url);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To launch a new instance of the browser, implement the below code sample:

```
// Store the current window url
String url = driver.getCurrentUrl();

// Create a new instance to open a new window
WebDriver driver2 = new FirefoxDriver();    // Use your own browser driver that you are using

// Go to the intended page [i.e, foo or some other link]
driver2.navigate().to(foo);

// Continue your code here in the new window...

// Close the popup window now
driver2.quit();

// No need to switch back to the main window; driver is still valid.
// demonstrate that the initial driver is still valid.
url = driver.getCurrentUrl();
```

Comment: WebDriver driver2 = new FirefoxDriver(); I can't instantiate the browser. I'm using TestNG framework and instantiated the browser only once. If there is some another way out ,Please let me know.

Answer (score -2):

You can use below java script to open new window:

`((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.open(arguments[0])", "URL to open");`

Comment: Thanks for responding!! But this method is opening new link in the same old tab. I want to open new link say(facebook.com) in new browse window(new instance of browser) without closing previous window.

Comment: This opens a new tab, but not a new browser window as per the question.